Separate transform control for instances on points
I`m trying to make nodes system for control by 1 input value "hand fan-like" rotation of 5 objects group.
It means each of those object has different value for rotation on one of axis. Animation sample -

First, I create copies of objects on a curve with 5 points. Now I can rotate a specific object (defined by the index).

But when I try to copy this scheme for an object with a different index, a copy of all five objects appears. Question - how can I manipulate different objects in a group of created ones? Or is there perhaps a simpler solution to the problem in general?

It's not clear what you want to achieve. For a fan-like arrangement you could use a focal point as an input:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Sorry if my question was unclear - English is not my native language. I made an animated example of the desired result - https://ibb.co/VMD18MD .
It seems like your solution might work - but I can't find  the "Focal Node" in node editor.

And, anyway, even if those solution works for this particular case - is it possible to address different objects built on points (or to the points themselves), not one of them, but several at once. For example, to change not the rotation, but the size or material. But your solution, for this particular case, seems optimal - thank you very much!

"Focal Point", sorry ( correction to first comment)

@michaelkramenko This is why I've put the node name in parentheses, maybe I should use square brackets... Or Vector: Focal Point...

Yep, I got it later that it was your name for Vector node;-)Any way - I even cant recreate you result  - https://jmp.sh/s/TTKm0vf0Plm2UB99zrAs. But seems to me - I will continue to look the way for separate control for instances - hope will find solution. Thank you!

@michaelkramenko separate control is exactly the same, you just provide a field instead of a single vector value.

By "Separate control" i mean  you can add values from Group Input for each of created instances -https://i.sstatic.net/VNkBAwth.png independently, by their index .

@michaelkramenko you can't really do it in the modifier stack, but you can have external geometry that defines the values and yes, you can then read from this geometry as a field.
